# Duplicate question banner: amend banner to remove "before"

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

[image]

Since it is established that it is not a *rule per se* that a post must be marked as a duplicate of an *earlier* post, can we change the banner to reflect the fact? The word "before" suggests a temporal order inappropriate in many situations.

I suggest:

> "This question duplicates another post, which has one or more answers. If those answers do not fully address your question, please
>   ask a new question."

I class this as a bug because the banner is often incorrect.

I also believe the use of plural "those answers" should be qualified by "one or more answers" in the previous sentence.

Comment: I have a feeling I've seen this as a FR before - if not here, then on MSE.

Comment: @JonClements, Please delete if you find it (or mark as dup!).

Comment: I could of course just be imagining it... I hope not though - that means I need a much more interesting imagination... :)

Comment: "before" could refer to the closure, not the question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Hmm, I have to disagree. It says *asked before*..

Comment: There is a date in the banner, which you cut off. The other question was asked before that date. I know I'm nitpicking, but so is this question. This is far from a bug.

Comment: I might be thinking of a request where it was regarding the "[...] already has an **answer**. If those **answers** [...]" - I don't know what the outcome of that was - maybe Jeff and his giant S handled it :)

Comment: When exactly do you get to see this banner?

Comment: @JonClements in the spirit of this question, maybe you remember it on a question that will be asked in the future? :O!

Comment: @Patrice could be... wibbly wobbly timey wimey and all that...

Comment: The question that is proposed as the duplicate has been asked before the closure notice was posted; we don't duplicate to hypothetical questions that might be asked in the future.  It doesn't mean "before this question was asked" — it means "before now" (with now being neutral between 'now when the closure notice is posted' and 'now when you are reading the closure notice').

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, That may be the intention. But I doubt anyone should care *when* the post was marked as a dup (other than for audit purposes). If the meaning is genuinely *before now*, this is trivially true and doesn't need remarking. One could say "This question duplicates another post, which has one or more answers."

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141839/184981) on MSE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Agree, "*before*" is not always applicable, so it's worth changing in the banner.

But let's also change "*please ask a new question*", because what we're looking at was often already "*a new question*" being asked in the sense that most of the time it was posted after the linked duplicate.

Suggestion:

> "This question has been asked on another post with an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please formulate it in a new question."

The second mention of the word *question* (in "*address your question*") may eventually be changed to "*your concerns*" if we want to avoid the repetitions.

Comment: This seems kinda wordy.

Comment: @Shog9, so, I guess you can add [tag:status-declined] or [tag:status-bydesign]...